# Get rid of toast message when Spotify Track changes

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, spotify, toast-notifications

I am trying to figure out how to get rid of a toast message that pops up whenever a family member changes tracks in her Spotify app on her Galaxy S5 (Android 5.0).  It seems that most of the time when the track changes (either because the song ended or because she changed tracks), she would usually (but not always) get a toast message that says: `MP:com.samsung.MusicPlayer.playstatechanged`

I would appreciate any advice on how to get rid of this toast message.

Comment: Are you by any chance using [Simple Last.fm Scrobbler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adam.aslfms) app?

Comment: @Andrew I don't think so, but I will ask to make sure.

Comment: @AndrewT. UPDATE: I stand corrected, she said that she does indeed have the Simple Last.fm Scrobbler app installed.

Answer (score 0):

From the toast message,

> MP:com.samsung.MusicPlayer.playstatechanged

and comparing to a [source code](https://github.com/tgwizard/sls/blob/master/src/com/adam/aslfms/receiver/SamsungMusicReceiver.java), it seems that the user is using [Simple Last.fm Scrobbler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adam.aslfms).

The app also supports many music players, such as

> Supported apps: Android Music Player, HTC Hero/Sense Music Player, Google Music, PlayerPro, Meridian Player, MixZing, Archos Music Player, Rhapsody Android, Vanilla Music Player, bTunes, ³ (cubed), WIMP, Zimly, Just Playlists, PowerAMP, Winamp, myTouch 4G, RockOn, jukefox, DAAP Media Player, Folder Player, GoneMAD Music Player, MIUI Music Player, ServeStream, Default Sony Ericsson/Xperia Music Player, Neutron Music Player, Music2Dance2, Rdio, DeaDBeeF, Music Pump XBMC Remote (Beta), JRTStudio Android Music Player, Music Folder Player, Apollo, LG Music Player, Now Playing, Shuttle Music Player, My Cloud Player, SoundSeeder, Amazon Music, more...

Uninstalling the app will remove the toast message when playing musics with listed players.

Comment: There are some things that I need to clarify: 1) I still cannot understand why the toast message is related Samsung default music player even though the user is using Spotify. 2) I'm not sure if it's possible to remove the toast message without uninstalling the app. Perhaps setting "Notify now playing" to off might work, but I can't get this app work, so I need confirmation for this.

Comment: as I previously stated, she does indeed have this app installed.  I have already asked her to send me a screenshot of the app settings and had suggested that she tries disabling that setting or changing how often it updates, even before seeing this message.  I will let you know if either of those options solves the problem.

Comment: No prob, take your time and thanks for informing me. I just want to know if there's another way other than uninstalling it :)

Comment: Thank you for your patients, she hasn't got back to me yet.  I am trying to avoid that as well, as she says she has used both apps for years without any problems (We recently upgraded to the S5)